# The sum of the sum of algebraic progression

Tags: python

```
N=int(input())
a=((1+N)*1000)
a=int(a)
s=((a/2)*N/1000)
s=int(s)
print((a/2),N)
print(s%N)
```

It's simple [algebraic progression sum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Lt4j.png), then **2 ≤ N ≤ 10^100**

> if N=1000000000 (10^9) after programme I have: s=500000000500000000 - it's normal, but if I have N>10^9 for example
> N=1000000000000 (10^10) s=50000000005000003584 etc.

How to fix it?)
What gives 3584

Comment: Perhaps you want `//` rather than `/`. Keep all your number ints to avoid the round-off error that you seem to be getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to fix it: change the division operators (`/`) to floor division operators (`//`).

```
N=int(input())
a=((1+N)*1000)
a=int(a)
s=((a//2)*N//1000)
s=int(s)
print((a//2),N)
print(s%N)
```

Here's the same code with better formatting and the explicit `int` type conversions combined into the variable definition:

```
N = int(input())
a = (1 + N) * 1000
s = (a // 2) * N // 1000
print((a // 2), N)
print(s % N)
```

Why this works: *Standard* division in Python will convert the dividend and the divisor to floating point numbers, resulting in a quotient that is also a floating point number. Floor division will not convert the dividend or the divisor, and will result in an integer. For more reading on this issue, check out [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) on the Python documentation